# Why isn't it sending the values from the correct row via Email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below sends one email containing the name of the item, its version and its current status, once the user makes some changes. Since the product can go through 06 statuses, there is one column for each status, where the script will mark "Sim" if an email has already been sent containing the update on that item.

The code marks the right rows and columns, but the message contains data for another product, instead.

I got the `MailApp` in the loop, tried adding a counter to stop it from sending as it loops through the rows, but no success so far.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "Sim";
function sendEmails() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A7:s3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 48)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var productList = [];
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (rowData[18] === "Estudo" || rowData[18] === "Desenvolvimento" || rowData[18] === "Aprovação" || rowData[18] === "Ativo" || rowData[18] === "Cancelado" || rowData[14] === "Descontinuado") {
      var status = rowData[18];
      var emailEstudo = rowData[42];    
      var emailDesenvolv = rowData[43];
      var emailAprov = rowData[44];
      var emailAtivo = rowData[45];
      var emailCancelado = rowData[46];
      var emailDescont = rowData[47];
      if (emailDesenvolv != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Desenvolvimento") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 44).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
      } else if(emailEstudo != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Estudo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 43).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailAprov != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Aprovação") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 45).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailAtivo != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Ativo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 46).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailCancelado != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Cancelado") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 47).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailDescont != EMAIL_SENT && status === "Descontinuado") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 48).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
      var produto = rowData[1];
      var versao = rowData[2];
      var lastUpdated = rowData[19];
      var lastUpdatedAsDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastUpdated, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") + "hs";
      var usuario = rowData[20];
      var emailTo = file.getOwner().getEmail();
      var subject = "O produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + " " +", mudou de status.";
      var message =  "<HTML><BODY>"
      + "<P>Olá!"
      //+ "<br><br />"
      + "<P>O status do produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + ", foi atualizado para " + "<b>" +status +"</b>" + "."
      //+ "<brr /><br />"
      + "<br>Data da última atualização:  </b>" + lastUpdatedAsDate + "<br />"
      + "<br>Usuário: </b>" + usuario + "<br />"
      + "<br /><br />"    
      //+ "<br>Clique para explorar detalhes, ou para atualizar o status: </b>" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pL_AMKVtH4dGk1U7VWMeg590MxtNe7VY4gRqm_GhrM/edit?usp=sharing" + "<br />" 
      + "<br /><br />"  
      + "</HTML></BODY>";  
    }  

  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({
          name: "P&D - PB",
          to: emailTo,
          //cc: emailCC,
          subject: subject, 
          htmlBody: message
        });
}
```

Here's a [link to the data.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N6znnKQIIDvTK1A4PLgQbLxAdTXTQ53HncaeeoQ77zE/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's a print that explains the challenge:
[image]

I appreciate your help in finding where the problem sits besides me in this chair!

Comment: This probably isn't the only error but this `var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); ` should be this `var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; `

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Thanks anyway, @Cooper!

Comment: How do know it's the wrong row?

Comment: Are you running this with an onEdit trigger?

Comment: @Cooper, It states "Sim" on Column 44, from row 2 to 6, as it should, as this is these are the empty ones, but it brings data from rows 17 to 21, as if it was emailAtivo.
...and this will run on a time trigger.

Comment: Which is the criteria for which you want to send out an email?

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka, I guess this is to be within the else if statements. I thought that once the row met those 02 criteria, the relating columns data would be considered within the variables that amke up the email... Do I then have to set empty variables and puth it the columns' data I want within these else if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code as it is now overwrites the variables `produto`, `versao` and `message` in each loop iteration where `if` condition is fullfilled
- Your `MailApp.sendEmail()` request is run only once - after exiting the `for` loop, with the last value of `message`
- What you probably want is to place `sendMail()` inside the `if` statement, after defining `message`, so that an email will be sent for every row where the condition `if (rowData[18] === "Estudo" || rowData[18] === "Desenvolvimento" || rowData[18] === "Aprovação" || rowData[18] === "Ativo" || rowData[18] === "Cancelado" || rowData[14] === "Descontinuado")` is fullfilled
- More precisely, if you do not want the email to be sent for all cases of the fulfillment of the outer `if` statement to be sent, but only in case of one of the inner `if` or `else if` cases (it is hard for me to estimate which is the condition under which you want to send the email) - you need to paste `sendMail()` inside of the respective `if` condition
- As it is now, the mail is being sent after looping through all rows and overwriting `message` in each iteration (when the outer `if` condition is fullfilled)

UPDATE

If you want to send one email per combination of `status`, `versao` and `produto`, you can implement and additional conditional statement where you query for the update of those three parameters before sending a new email out:

```
if(rowData[1] != produto && rowData[2] != versao && rowData[18] != status ){
  ...
  MailApp.sendEmail...
}
```

Full sample:

```
//Here, I don't see how this is going to avoid sending duplicates
function SendEmail() {
  var mgrcol=4;
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var rg=sheet.getDataRange();
  var emailTo = file.getOwner().getEmail();

  var values=rg.getValues();
  var productList=[];
  var html='';
  for(var i=1;i<values.length;i++) {
    if(productList.indexOf(values[i][0])==-1 && productList.indexOf(values[i][2])==-1) {
      //mgrA.push(vA[i][3]);
      productList.push(values[i]); // Joga toda a linha que será usada pra dar os dados para o email.
    }
  }
  var productObj={}
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<values.length;j++) {
      if(productList[i]==values[j][0] && productList[i]==values[j][2]){
        if(productObj.hasOwnProperty(productList[i])) {
          productObj[productList[i]]+=Utilities.formatString('~~~%s<br />%s<br />%s',values[j][0],values[j][2],values[j][18]);
        }else{
          productObj[productList[i]]=Utilities.formatString('%s<br />%s<br />%s',values[j][0],values[j][2],values[j][18]);
        }                                               
      } 
    }
  }
  Logger.log(productList);
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++) {
    var tA=productObj[productList[i]].split('~~~'); //This is the line presenting the error.
    var s='Status atualizado<br /></br />';
    for(var j=0;j<tA.length;j++) {
      s+=tA[j].toString() + '<br />'; 
    }
    s+='<hr widht="100" />';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(productList[i], 'User Names and Emails', null, {htmlBody:s})
    html+=Utilities.formatString('Email Recipient: <strong>%s</strong><br />',productList[i]) + s;//debug 
  }
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);//debug
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Emails');//debug
}

/*This is the code I was trying to put together, but ran into difficulties when 
fetching arow of data for each product to send the email and statig Email_Sent
*/

var EMAIL_SENT = "Sim";

function sendEmails() {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ArquivoItens");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A7:s3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 48)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var produto = "";
  var versao = "";
  var status = "";
  var emailTo = file.getOwner().getEmail();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (rowData[18] === "Estudo" || rowData[18] === "Desenvolvimento" || rowData[18] === "Aprovação" || rowData[18] === "Ativo" || rowData[18] === "Cancelado" || rowData[14] === "Descontinuado") {
      //var updateAsDate = new Date(rowData[13]);
      //var update = Utilities.formatDate(updateAsDate, "GMT" , "dd/MM/yyyy" );
      if(rowData[1] != produto && rowData[2] != versao && rowData[18] != status ){
        produto = rowData[1];
        versao = rowData[2];
        status = rowData[18];  
        //var emailCC = file.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail()]}).join(",");      
        var lastUpdated = rowData[19];
        var lastUpdatedAsDate = Utilities.formatDate(lastUpdated, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") + "hs";
        var usuario = rowData[20];
        var message =  "<HTML><BODY>"
        + "<P>Olá!"
        //+ "<br><br />"
        + "<P>O status do produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + ", foi atualizado para " + "<b>" +status +"</b>" + "."
        //+ "<brr /><br />"
        + "<br>Data da última atualização:  </b>" + lastUpdatedAsDate + "<br />"
        + "<br>Usuário: </b>" + usuario + "<br />"
        + "<br /><br />"    
        //+ "<br>Clique para explorar detalhes, ou para atualizar o status: </b>" + "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15pL_AMKVtH4dGk1U7VWMeg590MxtNe7VY4gRqm_GhrM/edit?usp=sharing" + "<br />" 
        + "<br /><br />"  
        + "</HTML></BODY>";
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          name: "P&D - PB",
          to: emailTo,
          //cc: emailCC,
          subject: subject, 
          htmlBody: message
        });      
      }
      var emailEstudo = rowData[42];    
      var emailDesenvolv = rowData[43];
      var emailAprov = rowData[44];
      var emailAtivo = rowData[45];
      var emailCancelado = rowData[46];
      var emailDescont = rowData[47];
      var subject = "O produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + " " +", mudou de status.";
      Logger.log(rowData[18]);
      if (emailDesenvolv != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Desenvolvimento") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 44).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      } else if(emailEstudo != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Estudo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 43).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailAprov != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Aprovação") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 45).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailAtivo != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Ativo") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 46).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailCancelado != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Cancelado") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 47).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }else if(emailDescont != EMAIL_SENT && rowData[18] === "Descontinuado") {  // Prevents sending duplicates 
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 48).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
      Logger.log(usuario);

    }
  }
  Logger.log(usuario);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation. I could place ´´´sendMail´´´ within the inner if statements, but since there are multiple rows meeting the criteria, it'd send one email for each row, while this'd have to be one email only, despite the number of rows.

Comment: If you want to send only one message containing several rows, you can define `message` as an empty string at the beginning of your function and inside your loop, whenever the right condition for a row is fullfilled, you can add extra text to the message body with `message += "<P>Olá!"
      + "<P>O status do produto " + produto + ", versão " + versao + ...` rather than overwriting the message body.

Comment: These rows that meet the criteria relate to the same item. So the email should not contain the data from all these rows, but rather resume it into one. I've tried declaring an empty variable message, but the content gets repeated in the body according to the rows meeting the criteria...

Comment: Can you put in words what you want do? Something like: " For all rows check status in column S, go to the column where the header corresponds to the status in S and check if the corresponding cell contains "Sim". If not - set it to "Sim". Then ... and send email that contains all rows where.... Send only one email for each product but several emails if there is more than one different product in column B...?".

Comment: Just added a visual example of the steps to take. Danke!

Comment: Thanks! So do you have only one product in your sheet but different statuses? Do you want to send one email per status? If there will be more than one column entry without "Sim" (different versions, different products) how do you want to summarize it into one email?

Comment: The same item and version will go through the statuses and will have its relating status colum marked with "Sim". Upon each change, one email informing that the product X, version Y has changed of status.

Comment: I hope I understood your issue correctly now and updated my code with a sample of how to send one email per combination of `produto`, `versao` and `status`. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hi, again! I've included the 'SendMail' in the inner if statements and it almost works right. The only issue is that if it goes thru different product/versao, but with the same status, it repeats the first item found and sends only one email, while it should send one email for each combination of product/versao/status. When I log these criteria, it show only one item repeated.

Comment: Are your rows sorted? In this case, if you replace the AND operator through OR it should work as desired, that is  `if(rowData[1] != produto || rowData[2] != versao || rowData[18] != status )` instead of `if(rowData[1] != produto && rowData[2] != versao && rowData[18] != status )`

Comment: It's sorted in the sense of having all rows for one product,versao and status together,not by date or any other key. I'll try asap. Thanks.

Comment: U rock! Thanks a million!